# Clarification regarding uploading jars to artifactory using maven

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

As per the above link , we can use maven plugin to upload jars to our own internal artifcatory.
What I observed is that transitive dependencies are not getting uploaded to the artifactory .
We need to manually specify all the transitive dependencies.

Is there any way to enforce that all transitive dependencies are also uploaded to the artifactory based upon the main dependency specified in the pom.xml ?

Or is this achievable using gradle ?

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. A project is expected to publish only the artifacts it produces, and declare what dependencies it needs in a "manifest" file which is a pom file in the case of maven. The dependencies are published by their own respective projects. Can you maybe describe why you're trying to publish dependencies?

Comment: We maintain a internal artifactory for our development team . So if the development team requests to upload a certain jar ( e.g: spark 2.0.0 ) , then this jar has to be uploaded to artifactory along with all the dependencies of this jar.  This will ensure all relevant dependencies are available within intranet and developers need not connect to internet maven every time.

Comment: See gradle-fury on git hub.  It will fix your poms dependency declarations

Comment: So you're sort of trying to archive deployment packages? you should look into the gradle application/distribution plugins. These plugins can create a zip or tar.gz artifact containing all applicaiton jars + dependencies required to run the application in one package. Use artifactory to then publish this artifact.

Comment: Alternatively, you can setup artifactory to cache/proxy a remote repo. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common practice is setting up one or more [remote repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-RemoteRepositories), proxying  external repositories, such a JCenter and Maven Central, which contains the 3rd party dependencies you need. The remote repositories serves as a caching proxy.
Usually you aggregate the remote repositories (together with [local](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories) ones) using a [virtual repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-VirtualRepositories). This virtual repository is the one used by developers and CI servers. This way developers only need to deal with a single URL.

In case your organization does not allow direct internet connection and developers cannot use remote repositories, you can use a setup of 2 Artifactory instances:

- One instance inside the internal network with no internet connection
- Second instance in the DMZ with internet connection

The idea is to resolve dependencies in the DMZ, approve them (or not) and copy the approved ones to the internal network.
You can read more about such a setup in the following blog post by Shani Levy - [Using Artifactory with an air gap](https://www.jfrog.com/blog/using-artifactory-with-an-air-gap/)